# How to pass function from parent to child page in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

So I have navbar which I'm going to extend into every page, but in navbar I want to make login box, so the question is, how do I make sure that all the functions from navbar will work in child pages?

Comment: you might be already using jinja template, so..write the nav bar in the first template and keep extending it into child templates